# How to auto sync a folder on my external hard drive with a folder on my computer

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, sync, automation

I would like to know if there is a way to somehow auto sync a folder on my external hard drive with a folder on my computer.

You see, previously my computer's internal Hard Drive got damaged and all my data erased. So now I am wondering, as if I have only a single folder which is important to me, like really important. It would be very safe for me to know that this one folder is auto syncing with my external hard drive's, which is always plugged into my computer. So in case of my computer's Internal hard drive crash, I would know that my data is all safe on my external hard drive.

*Or perhaps there is a more simple way out there using which I will be able to have data auto syncing from my internal computers drive to somewhere I can access from any computer.*

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you could do is setup the HDD directly to your home modem/router and use is as a share. Once you have this setup, you could setup recurrent robo-copies via some job. You can utilize the following options:

`/MON:n : MONitor source; run again when more than n changes seen.`

`/MOT:m : MOnitor source; run again in m minutes Time, if changed.`

This is the easiest solution to setup via a command prompt.

If you are after a question, try this [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/557132/continuously-copy-all-file-changes-from-one-folder-to-another-on-change-windows).

Comment: Where does the question say he had a modem/router where he can attach a hard drive?

Comment: The rest of your answer is just copied from [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/913808/337631). Rather than link "solution" to another question, you should flag **this** question as a duplicate instead of answering.

Comment: David, re point one please see the use of the word `could` and, he has internet does he not? Secondly the /MON is actually a flag within the CMD `help robocopy` so there's not much I can change there. I do agree re the flag as duplicate but do not believe I can that yet.